# Mongodb is not working upon restart in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I had to force a restart of my linux computer and upon turning back on, nothing related to my Mongodb installation is functioning properly.

My rails app, using Mongoid, is giving this error:

```
Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

on attempting to load a page and a similar error in the rails console.

Everything was running smoothly before and I am not sure how to right this ship.

Answer (score 3):

I generally get this error when the mongo daemon is not running. Try running something like this:

```
sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend
```

The method used to automatically start on system boot will vary depending on your OS. What flavor of Linux do you run?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10, running that command produced this result:
    forked process: 7854
    all output going to: /var/log/mongodb.log
Nothing changed with my error, but maybe I need to do more. I am pretty blind in this area.

Comment: Check that the mongo process is running with `ps -fe | grep mongod`. Then try connecting to the mongo shell by running `mongo`; within the shell, run `db.version()` to see the version of Mongodb shell. If all this works fine, rails should connect to mongodb without problems.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know it is right or wrong way but it always work for me

> rm /data/db/mongod.lock
>
> mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
>
> mongod --dbpath /data/db